# Problemas autenticacion graphql-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

Hola estoy siguiendo una documentacion para aprender la autenticacion con rails y graphql (https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-ruby/4-authentication/) todo bien hasta que se tuvo que hacer una mutacion para el usersignin, se supone que una vez que verifica el usuario el objeto me deberia devolver un token pero este me entrega un error.

```
{
"error": {   "message": "undefined method `credentials' for #<GraphqlTutorial::Application:0x000055a348f9c3d8>",
}
```

La configuracion que segui es esta:

```
module Mutations
class SignInUser < BaseMutation
    null true

    argument :email, Types::AuthProviderEmailInput, required: false

    field :token, String, null: true
    field :user, Types::UserType, null: true

    def resolve(email: nil)
        return unless email

        user = User.find_by email: email[:email]

        return unless user
        return unless user.authenticate(email[:password])

        crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base.byteslice(0..31))
        token = crypt.encrypt_and_sign("user-id:#{ user.id }")

        { user: user, token: token }
    end
 end
end
```

Estoy percibiendo que puede que sea en la linea para la variable crypt en donde se crea el token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que estás usando una versión antigua de rails, ya que [`Rails.application.credentials`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/Rails/Application/credentials) está disponible desde [rails 5.2](https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336).
Probablemente estés usando [`config/secrets.yml`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml), para lo cual deberías acceder usando `Rails.application.secrets.nombre_de_tu_key`, si no, cualquier string fijo debería funcionar, ya que en general `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new` requiere un string que sea siempre el mismo, para luego usarlo en generar el token de usuario.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta estimado, efectivamente, todo era un alcance con las versiones, el chico del tutorial usaba 5.2, yo estaba en 5.1.. en la mañana al leer docu me habia dado cuenta que para mi version estaba usando la que me dices config/secrets. ahora me funciona el token ! :D gracias